# How to change a checked event to an onclick event?

Tags: javascript

How I would change this simple function into an onclick event using a button, rather than a checkbox? I am really new to JavaScript.

```
function showhide() {
        if (document.getElementById('toggle').checked == true) {
            document.getElementById('hidethis').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('hidethis').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exactly, what do you want with onclick event? You want hide and unhide element when user click button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how, without using jQuery:

```js
function showhide() {
  var hidethis1 = document.getElementById('hidethis1');
  var hidethis2 = document.getElementById('hidethis2');

  if (getComputedStyle(hidethis1).getPropertyValue('display') === 'none') {
    hidethis1.style.display = 'block';
    hidethis2.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    hidethis1.style.display = 'none';
    hidethis2.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

document.getElementById('clickthis').addEventListener('click', showhide);
```

```css
#hidethis2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="clickthis">Click Me</button>
<div id="hidethis1">Hide Me (1)</div>
<div id="hidethis2">Hide Me (2)</div>
```

If you want to toggle more than two elements, you should give each of the elements the same class, and use a for loop.

Comment: is there a way to hide the 'hidethis' and with another onclick of the same button bring up another div? I'm trying to avoid creating another button.

Comment: have you got any useful links where I can learn how to use a loop?

Comment: [MDN `for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand how a loop works :(  if you have several divs. Should I just keep searching until i understand ?

Comment: @JackYouitt there are plenty of resources available on stackoverflow explaining for loops, so yes you should keep searching until you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Better use with [`classList.toggle`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj47bPw3aPUAhULtY8KHRA8Ci8QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fprop_element_classlist.asp&usg=AFQjCNEXXWxDd-cJNK0gx8na1nqCIaiNiw&sig2=TuGZFtpEoorIsTO9b7fVbw) function .It toggle the className

```js
function showhide() {
  document.getElementById('hidethis').classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showhide()">Click Me</button>
<div id="hidethis">Text</div>
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Its just name . But the property is `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="yourbutton">Click</button>
<script type="text/javsacript">$("#yourbutton").on("click", function() {
    if (document.getElementById('toggle').checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('hidethis').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hidethis').style.display = 'none';
    }
});</script>
```

Hope it helps

And dont forget to include jquery plugin`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to use jQuery

```
$(".buttonClass").click(function(){
  $("#hidethis").toggleClass("displayNone");
})

//style code
.displayNone{ display: none;}
```